# How to combine two fields in Form to one field from Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, expressionbuilder

An example is trying to combine first name and last name into fullname from a table thats called employee. What expression do I type in the Control Source? I've typed FullName: `[First] & " " & [Last]` but it kept saying error.

Comment: "kept saying error" - Yeah but *which*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=[First] & " " & [Last]
```

Should do it.

To avoid complications with nulls use:

```
=Nz([First], "") & " " & Nz([Last], "")
```

Comment: Their is a list of names and I'm using the same expression you've mentioned but the first list of name keeps appearing. How do I change it to the next name?